# Words for "East" and "West" in Spanish?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sinónimos, vocabulario

The words I learned when beginning Spanish for *east* and *west* are '**este**' and '**oeste**', which are basically cognates of their English equivalents.

But I've been told that there are other words to denote *east* and *west*: '**oriente**' and '**poniente**'. How did these words get those connotations? Are there times when you would use these words and not 'este' and 'oeste'?

Also the main words for *north* and *south* are 'norte' and 'sur', which again are basically cognates. Are there non-cognate words in Spanish that connote *north* and *south*?

---

Note: there is a follow-up of this question in [What are the Spanish words for North and South and how are they different?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31382/1674).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Oriente* and *Poniente* are words that come from Latin/Italian.

The **former** comes from *oriĕns*, from the verb *orīri*, "to be born"; this refers to the sun coming out in the morning from east. Another word for it is "Levante". The **latter** comes from the verb *ponĕre* in Latin, more exactly from *ponens*; it refers to the sun going down. Also "Occidente" is used for this, like pleasedontbelong pointed out. "Occidente" comes from *occidĕre*, "to fall, to set (refering to the sun)".

The opposites work like this:

- Occidente - Oriente
- Poniente - Levante

I'm not sure there really is a strict rule for when you should use one of the other one, but I suppose it depends on your choice.

The other words for "**north**" and "**south**" are "*septentrional*" or "*norteño*" for the former, and "*meridional*" for the latter.

Comment: you could also say "occidente" instead of "poniente"... it's more common

Comment: Yeah "occidente" is the opposite of "oriente", you're right! :)

Comment: De nada. A propósito, "Saliente" y "Naciente" se usan también para "Este" y "ocaso" se usa para "Oeste".

Comment: Septentrional means northern, not North. And the same for meridional, which means southern. The nouns are: [septentrión](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=septentri%C3%B3n) and [mediodía](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=mediodía)

Comment: @MikMik Where did I say that? I said "the other words for... are...", that's different.

Comment: En Chile para ubicarnos en las ciudades usamos el par _oriente - poniente_, que no es muy lógico pero estamos acostumbrados.