# Origen y evolución de las palabras "norte" y "sur"

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos

En la pregunta *[Words for "East" and "West" in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/396/12637)* descubrimos que las palabras con las que hoy día designamos los puntos cardinales son cognados del inglés. Efectivamente, consultando la RAE vemos que todas provienen primero del francés, y en última instancia del inglés antiguo:

```
español    francés    ingl.ant.
-------------------------------
norte      nord       norþ
sur        sud        sûþ
este       est        ēast
oeste      ouest      west
```

Me llamó la atención que todas mantienen en su pronunciación esa última letra *t* o *d* (adaptada como *te*) de las versiones francesas menos *sur*. Entiendo que *est* y *ouest* se adaptaran como *este* y *oeste*, pero me resulta curioso que *nord* y *sud* se adaptaran la primera siguiendo el patrón acabado en *te* y la segunda no. ¿Cuál fue el motivo para esto? ¿Por qué no "nor", convirtiendo la *d* final en *r* como en "sur", o "sute", convirtiendo la *d* final en *te* como en norte? ¿Cuándo se incorporaron estas palabras al español? Cuando lo hicieron, ¿tenían la misma forma que hoy día?

Al menos viendo las palabras originales en francés se entiende por qué decimos [*nor**d**este*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qbx6K5h) o [*su**d**oeste*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YdUn343).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La diferencia fonética más clara entre las palabras francesas que designan los puntos cardinales es que la palabra para "sur" termina (y terminaba desde el principio) en una consonante simple, /d/ o /r/ (había alguna vacilación ya en francés antiguo), mientras que las otras terminaban en un grupo de dos consonantes (/rt/ y /st/). En francés antiguo *norht* o *north* pasó a *nord*; las consonantes finales tendieron a perderse y por eso hoy *nord* termina fonéticamente con /r/, pero ése es un detalle.

En castellano hemos tendido a evitar los grupos complejos de consonantes, por uno de dos medios: epéntesis (añadir una vocal) o elisión (borrar una consonante). En *norte*, *este* y *oeste* se usó una /e/ epentética, quizá porque la /t/ final de las palabras francesas se oía muy claramente, quizá porque suprimir esta /t/ implicaba decir *nor, es, oés*, palabras muy cortas y fácilmente confundibles. (Otra rectificación que hicimos en castellano fue el hiato al comienzo de *oeste*; por lógica deberíamos decir *hueste*, ya que el francés nos pasó directamente la palabra monosilábica anglosajona *west*.)

En el caso de *sur* o *sud* ambas consonantes finales eran y son perfectamente posibles en castellano (cuando están solas), de manera que no había por qué añadirles una /e/ epentética para soportarlas. (Tampoco era esperable que se la elidiera dejando *su*.) Por analogía con los otros puntos cardinales podría haberse añadido una /e/ de todas maneras, pero la analogía no es predecible y esto nunca ocurrió.

Comment: Estoy leyendo *esperpéntica* todo el rato en lugar de *epentética*.

Comment: @blonfu ya somos dos.